# Python star operator in assignments

Tags: python

in Python 3, the following code has a valid syntax:

```
>> *firsts, last = [1,2,3,4]
```

and it will result in having:

```
>> firsts
[1,2,3]
>> last
4
```

Pretty convenient. However, this syntax is not valid under Python 2. Is there a better way to achieve the same results than doing this:

```
>> firsts = [1,2,3,4]
>> last = firsts.pop()
```

Which is fine, but I love the elegance of the Python3 solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have some list of items `l`, you can do this:

```
firsts, last = l[:-1], l[-1]
```

It isn't quite as neat as the unpacking, but is a single line. Note that it will only work with iterables you can index, though.

Comment: The advantage of Python 3 is that it works with any iterable... This solution needs indexable by ranges.

Comment: That's what I've opted for in the end. If only we weren't forced to use Python 2, sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it seems to work

```
 firsts, last = [[1,2,3],4]
```